# Do I have to use container or container-fluid in grid system?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I know the similar questions already exist on Stackoverflow but I think the exact one doesn't exist.

Most people say

"You should place `.row` in `.container` and `.col` should be wrapped by `.row`".

But I don't perfectly get it.

I am aware of I should wrap `.col` with `.row` 
BUT Do I have to wrap `.row` with `.container` or `.container-fluid`?

Is it mandatory?

I think the code below does work well as grid system.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--
    <div class="container-fluid">
    -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">
      B
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">
      C
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      D
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--
    </div>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`container` and `container-fluid` provide the necessary horizontal padding (15px) for the negative margins added to `row`.

If you put `row` within an element with less-than 15px horizontal padding, it will overflow horizontally.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- with container -->
<div class="border container mb-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm border">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm border">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm border">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- no padding, this one will be messed up -->
<div class="border p-0 mb-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm border">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm border">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm border">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- with enough padding -->
<div class="border px-5 mb-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm border">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm border">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm border">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of having container or container-fluid as parent of a .row

but as you know .row has -15px margin left and right so you need a parent with 15px padding left and right, If you don't use that your row will be overflown.

but if you have a parent with at least 15px or more padding left and right then you are good to go.